# AngularJS and Jasmine: mocking services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

I am having trouble mocking the dependency of the following service "broadcaster" over the service "pushServices".

```
angular.module('broadcaster', ['pushServices']);

angular.module('broadcaster').service('broadcaster', [
    '$rootScope', '$log', 'satnetPush',
    function ($rootScope, $log, satnetPush) {
        // .. contents ..
    };
};
```

The Jasmine spec is as follows:

```
describe('Test Broadcaster Service', function () {
    'use strict';

    var broadcasterService, mockPushService;
    beforeEach(module('broadcaster'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

        broadcasterService = $injector.get('broadcaster');
        mockPushService = {
            getSomething: function () { return 'mockReturnValue'; }
        };

        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('satnetPush', mockPushService);
        });

    }));

    it('should return a non-null broadcaster object', function () {
        expect(broadcasterService).not.toBeNull();
    });
```

});

The error that I get is the typical "Unknown provider":

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) Test Broadcaster Service should return a non-null broadcaster object FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $pusherProvider <- $pusher <- satnetPush <- broadcaster
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=%24pusherProvider%20%3C-%20%24pusher%20%3C-%20satnetPush%20%3C-%20broadcaster
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I be injecting the dependency instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to $provide your mock service before you get the service under test from $injector. Then the 'satnetPush' will exist:

```
describe('Test Broadcaster Service', function () {
    'use strict';

    var broadcasterService, mockPushService;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('broadcaster');

        module(function ($provide) {
            mockPushService = {
                getSomething: function () { return 'mockReturnValue'; }
            };

            $provide.value('satnetPush', mockPushService);
        });

        inject(function($injector) {
            broadcasterService = $injector.get('broadcaster');
        })
    });

    it('should return a non-null broadcaster object', function () {
        expect(broadcasterService).not.toBeNull();
    });
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greus/LL5j8dgv/)